# Efficient conversion between boxed and unboxed vectors

Tags: haskell, vector

What is the recommended way of converting between `Data.Vector.Unboxed` and `Data.Vector`. Specifically, I need to map a function over a vector which converts an unboxable element type such as `Int` to a non-unboxable one such as `Text`. I assume going through an intermediate list is not going to be very efficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [convert](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Generic.html#g:37) function from `Data.Vector.Generic` to change vector types, followed by a `map` to do the per-element conversion.

Comment: Also useful fact: it fuses well!